# Akka - Sender[null] sent message of type

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I have a spray route where I declare one of my actors.

```
val myActor = actorRefFactory.actorSelection("/user/my-actor")
```

And my route looks like:

```
get {
  path(Segment / Segment) { (poolId, trackId) =>
    respondWithMediaType(MediaTypes.`application/json`) {
      val request = Request(poolId, trackId)

      val f = (myActor ? request)
        .recoverWith {
          case a: AskTimeoutException =>
            Future.failed[StandardRoute](throw new Exception(s"We got a timeout", a))

          case e: Exception => Future.failed[StandardRoute](throw new Exception(s"We got an error", e))
        }

      onComplete(f) {
        case Success(resp) => complete(OK, resp)

        case Failure(e) =>
          log.error(s"Fatal request error: $trackId / $poolId", e)
          complete(InternalServerError, ErrorCodes.ErrorNotHandled)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sometimes, I can see when I get lots of requests at the same time, some of them may fail with the following message:

> Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on
>   [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://default/), Path(/user/my-actor)]] after
>   [8000 ms]. Sender[null] sent message of type
>   "my.company.messages.Request".

The problem is if I take the same request and try to send it again, it works, only sometimes this happens and I have no idea how to solve that.

The actor indeed is doing a lot of things with lots of futures inside until it returns a value to the spray route.

Inside the actor, I create a val called replyTo in order to keep the value of the sender.

Any ideas on why sometimes I get this error?

**EDIT**

Just an example on how I'm managing the myActor:

```
class MyActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  private implicit val timeout = Timeout(8.seconds)

  def receive = {

    case req: Request =>

      val replyTo = sender()

      doOneThing.map { one =>

        doSecondThing(one).map { sec =>
          replyTo ! sec
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Where doOneThing and doSecondThing are Futures... and I have a lot of them spread around this actor for different situations.

Comment: You should not be using throw with Future.failed. See: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@failed[T](exception:Throwable):scala.concurrent.Future[T]

Comment: @OlliHelenius good, but that does not help.

Comment: Does myActor sometimes take more than 8 seconds to respond?

Comment: @OlliHelenius hmm I don't believe in a normal situation, but now maybe this could happen on heavy load? I will try to increase and see what happens. But what I see very strange is the sender to be null, that makes no sense to me.

Comment: Ask pattern internally uses a temporary actor. As it is a temporary actor, the sender reference will change every time.
`val replyTo = sender()` will not work in this case if you use the same sender reference again and again. 
 Reference to code for `myActor` will help more to understand the problem.

Comment: @Yoda how can replyTo can not work on this case? Well, I have updated the question with an example of what myActor is... the code indeed is much complex, but you will understand that I have a lot of nested futures.

Comment: Your `replyTo` should work in this case, but it's more idiomatic to import `akka.pattern.ask` and use `pipeTo` to send to result of a `Future` to another actor.

Comment: @rgcase hmm so instead of using map or even onComplete, pipeTo is a great solution. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sender[null] that you're seeing is normal behaviour. The ask method `?` takes an implicit parameter `sender` with default value `ActorRef.noSender`. Normally, if you're inside an `Actor` you have an implicit `ActorRef` in scope called `self`, but since you're not in an `Actor` it's just taking the default.

It's likely that the cause of your error is that the `Actor` that receives your message just isn't responding in time.

Comment: probably... at the beginning I thought the Sender[null] was something completely different, but now looking at some comments, maybe my actor takes more than it should to complete some action in heavy load and I got this strange result. I will indeed start a refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using routing over here that's why you are getting the timeout exception.
for example,
suppose your one request taking 1 second to get executed.
and suppose you are getting 4 requests at a time and when the requests come to an actor it appends in a queue and for every request you are waiting for 8 seconds. so in the queue suppose 4th request will execute in 4 seconds so you will get the response within 8 seconds. But when 100 requests come at a time and your one actor will be available to process them and for the 100th request it will take 100 seconds to get executed but you are waiting only 8.second for the 100th request that's why you are getting the timeout exception.

so the solution is, you can use routing here for example -

system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(concurrency).props(Props(new MyActor())))

and you can set concurrency on your system available process. suppose so set concurrency value 100 so now for the 100th request, it will take only 2 seconds to get executed. so I think routing can be a solution.

and if you don't know how many requests will be there it may be 1k or maybe more then it then you can go with dynamic creation of the actor where you can create the actor dynamically as per the request. so whenever a request will come, your one separate actor will be there to give the service for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would get this kind of error when I didn't send back the response to sender correctly.

Incorrect (simply returning the value):

```
def receive = {
  case DataFetch =>
    data
}
```

Correct (sending the value to `sender`):

```
  def receive = {
    case DataFetch =>
      sender ! data
  }
```